# How to pass a C# variable with apostrophe through MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin, apostrophe

I'm having a problem inputting variables into my database. I've seen other posts on how to pass a variable through by just escaping it, but those solutions do not apply because I am getting my variable's through an API. I'm cycling though data with a foreach loop by the way.

```
level = "" + x.Account_Level + "";
name = "" + x.name + "";
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `data` (`level`, `name`) VALUES(" + level + ", " + name + ")";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Sometimes, a variable will come back with an apostrophe and will screw up the code. Is it possible to insert a slash before every apostrophe or is there a way like in PHP to just push the whole variable through with single quotes? Thanks!

**Edit:**
Would this work? I think I need to add the i to change the name of the parameter each loop, due to it claiming the parameter as already declared.

```
using (var web = new WebClient())
        {
        web.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        var jsonString = responseFromServer;
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var MatchesList = jss.Deserialize<List<Matches>>(jsonString);
        string connectString = "Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Uid=myUser;Pwd=myPass;";
        MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
        MySqlCommand command = connect.CreateCommand();
        int i = 1;


        connect.Open();
        foreach (Matches x in MatchesList)
        {

            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `data` (`level`, `name`) VALUES(?level" + i + ", ?name" + i + ")";

             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("level" + i, x.Account_Level);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("mode" + i, x.name);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            i++;
        }
        connect.Close();                    
    }
```

Comment: You should really use SQL parameters, your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks. As a nice side effect you also get rid of your problem that way.

Comment: look ip "c# mysql parameters"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty fix is to use something like:

```
level = level.Replace("'","whatever");
```

but there are still problems with that. It won't catch other bad characters and it probably won't even work for edge cases on the apostrophe.

The *best* solution is to not construct queries that way. Instead, learn how to use parameterised queries so that SQL injection attacks are impossible, and the parameters work no matter what you put in them (within reason, of course).

For example (off the top of my head so may need some debugging):

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
    "insert into data (level, name) values (?lvl, ?nm)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("lvl", level));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("nm", name)); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I've tried making parameters before and it just gets screwed up in a foreach loop. It just returns that I've already declared something like '@level' before. Would it be possible to use a count in a var i in the name of the parameter and use i++ every loop?

Comment: @Kragalon, yes, you _could_ do that. I wouldn't myself :-)

Comment: Is it a security issue or just inefficient?

Comment: It seems like it's the only option I have that this point. Being that I need to make parameters and previously, it malfunctions.

Comment: @Kragalon, construction of queries as you have it is a security issue in that it opens you up to SQL injection attacks. There are ways to get your DBMS to execute arbitrary instructions. Parameterised queries fixes that problem.