# How to pass a C# string to MySQL including special characters

Tags: c#, mysql, apostrophe

Well I already saw some posts on that, and the best answer I could find was to use [Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541370/how-to-pass-a-c-sharp-variable-with-apostrophe-through-mysql), but in my case not possible :

I made a separate library that send requests to MySQL or MSSQL, with the following function :

```
public long Insert(string query)
   {
      if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
      {
         if (isMySQL)
         {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.Replace("[v-steel].", ""), connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            long lastId = cmd.LastInsertedId;
            this.CloseConnection();
            return lastId;
         }
         else
         {
         using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query + "; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY () As NewID", MSconnection))
            {
               SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
               if (dataReader.HasRows)
               {
                  dataReader.Read();
                  long lastId = long.Parse(dataReader["NewID"].ToString().Trim());
                  return lastId;
               }
            }
         }
      }
      return -1;
   }
```

So as this function is global for any query/table, I cannot use parameters.

What I want on the end is be able to send in my database characters as apostroph, comma etc... and all what I found are Replace functions, or parameters, isn't there an "easier" way to implement in my functions Insert and Update, so I am sure I never get error messages, and these characters will be taken in account.
Usually I meet the problem to send back comments of users, that can write anything in comments.

Edit :

A second possibility would be to edit my request out of Insert function(before I send the query)

The request sent looks like that (in my concrete example) :

```
string requete = "INSERT INTO [v-steel].assemblage_avancement_histo(ID_ASS_AV,ID_USER,ID_OP,ID_OP_NEXT,COMM) VALUES(" + this.IdAssAv + "," + this.IdUser + "," + this.IdOp+","+this.IdOpNext+",\'"+this.Comm+"\')";
            this.ID=DataBase.Insert(requete);
```

As you could understand, my problem is met on "this.Comm" that are commentaries left by users, and I want to allow users to write anything they want.

**EDIT :**

According to MarcGravell comments, I added a new object ElementInput

```
public class ElementInput
{
   private string field;
   public string Field
   {
      get { return field; }
      set { field = value; }
   }
   private string valeur;
   public string Valeur
   {
      get { return valeur; }
      set { valeur = value; }
   }
 }
```

Then modified the Insert function as following :

```
public long Insert(string table,List<ElementInput> listElements)
  {
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
      if (isMySQL)
      {
        string query = "INSERT INTO [v-steel]." + table + "(";
        for(int i=0;i<listElements.Count();i++)
        {
          if(i>0)
          {
            query += ",";
          }
          query += listElements[i].Field;
        }
        query += ") values (";
        for (int i = 0; i < listElements.Count(); i++)
        {
          if (i > 0)
          {
            query += ",?valeur"+i;
          }
          else
          {
            query += "?valeur"+i;
          }
         }
         query += ")";
         MySqlCommand cmd= new MySqlCommand(query.Replace("[v-steel].", ""), connection);
         for(int i=0;i< listElements.Count(); i++)
         {
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("valeur"+i, listElements[i].Valeur));
         }
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         long lastId = cmd.LastInsertedId;
         this.CloseConnection();
         return lastId;
       }
       else
       {
           //same thing for MSSQL         
       }
      }
      return -1;
    }
```

The only thing remaining is edit all my functions calling Insert(), to send the list of fields to set.

**Edit (after 4 years)** : to who goes through that post, no need to lose time trying to do without parameters as I did, will be a loss of time, and someday you will finish doing so, so better change your habits earlier.

Comment: Sorry, but the only correct answer here is "parameters", and you seem to not want to do that. Do you have examples of what your `query` might look like, to see if we can't just parameterize it as input? Note: you could pass the parameters in parallel to the query (like how "dapper" does, for example, just as a simple object) - so your signature becomes `public long Insert(string query, object args)`. However, looking at the code: frankly, I suspect a tool like "dapper" would make the entire method redundant, as the caller could use `var id = connection.QuerySingle<long>(sql, new {...});` -

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, I don't know what is "dapper", I put an example of query in edited question

Comment: Well if I understood good, the only way for me would be when I make the request and I know there can be special characters, to add Replace("'","\'").Replace("\\","\\\\") (well I think I don't control good enough these special chars yet)

Comment: "dapper" is a tool that simplifies ADO.NET, making it much easier to work with parameters, commands, data-readers, etc. To put that in "dapper" terms: `request = "INSERT INTO ... , COMM) VALUES(@IdAssAv, @IdUser, @IdOp, @IdOpNext, ...)";` and just pass `this` as the parameters object - "dapper" will then add the `IdAssAv`, `IdUser`, `IdOp` etc members as names parameters automatically.

Comment: Yes, during that time I read on dapper official website. In fact I develop on C# since 2 years only, and for now I am developping an application for industrial sector, without any "web side", so I am not even sure I can say I develop on .NET (until now I understood .NET is a framework...). The point is I before developped on C++, then decided to develop this application in C# because "it is newer", but I am still discovering many useful things that are on C#, and not on C++... so I think for Dapper it is still early for me, thansk anyway, I guess I will continue using Replace functions then

Comment: I just want to be clear and unambiguous: the "replace" approach is a terrible idea and will leave you open to SQL injection vulnerabilities, i18n/l10n problems, and general bugs

Comment: @MarcGravell in fact I read it is a bad approach, that's why I looked for another solution, but as I understood, Parameters is the only way to solve it. Not a good new for me as I have to review all of my functions(almost hundred uses), but if this is the only way, I have no choice to review all my code.

Comment: @MarcGravell about this injection vulnerabilities, does it have an importance for a client application, I mean only customer will use my application, and they are responsibles if bad data is inputed? I understand it for a web application, but for such application is this something I may take in account anyway?

Comment: No need to use a special library like Dapper, `SqlCommand` has a `AddWithValue` method to add a parameter with a value https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @KarelFrajták if I understood good, this `AddWithValue` is when using `Parameters` ? So I believe what you say is the same as wrotten by MarcGravell before, so edit my Insert/Update methods as following : Insert(string table_name, List<string> fields, List<string> values), so make a foreach (string field in fields){...}

Comment: @MarcGravell could you please have a look at my Edit in question? I guess I understood it, but prefer to have a more "experimented" opinion before I change all my code. Thanks

Comment: @MarcGravell could you put your comment as an answer so I could accept it and close the question, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a C# variable with apostrophe through MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541370/how-to-pass-a-c-sharp-variable-with-apostrophe-through-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

replace ' as '' , i.e. this.Comm.Replace("'", "''")

```
string requete = "INSERT INTO [v-steel].assemblage_avancement_histo(ID_ASS_AV,ID_USER,ID_OP,ID_OP_NEXT,COMM) VALUES(" + this.IdAssAv + "," + this.IdUser + "," + this.IdOp+","+this.IdOpNext+",\'"+this.Comm.Replace("'", "''")+"\')";
        this.ID=DataBase.Insert(requete);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as explained in comments, this is not a good approach to use Replace for security reason (SQL injection vulnerabilities).

Comment: Yep, the only correct approach is to use parameters. WIth `Replace` you'll certainly not replace everything and it will only complicate your code.

Comment: Replace("'", "''") can void SQL injection vulnerabilities. string between '' just string , not sql command.

Comment: @windfog are you sure about it? Because until now, everywhere I looked it is written that this solution is to be avoided.

Comment: yea, I'm not absolutely sure about it . But i did not find how to input string from UI to implement sql injection  when i use this method several years ago.  Though i know like following format input  ['; your sql to inject] can cause sql injection when you did not replace.

Comment: Anyway,using parameters is the best way.

Comment: @windfog well, after 4 years, I finally used parameters everywhere. It's not easy to understand for beginners, but there is no doubt that this is the best (and only) way to do it correctly, if somebody goes through that post it may help.